# Is there a way to track internet connection speeds with Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, optimization

We have a client who says their website is slow on 3g. We want to compile a report about his users connection speeds through analytics which can show him if optimizing for 3g is worth the cost. Is this data possible to track / collect or is this a pipe dream?

Answer (score 3):

It is *kind of* possible. Allow me to explain:

It is possible to attempt to [measure visitor bandwidth using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583395/calculate-speed-using-javascript), but the results won't be reliably accurate. Additionally, this would also make the site load slower, which would further compound the speed issue. In this scenario, you would create a custom event in GA to fire off the JS function and report the results.

Another other way of approaching this would be to use a 3rd party log analysis software, like [Angelfish](http://analytics.angelfishstats.com/solutions/google-analytics-web-log-software/) or something similar. I haven't used this product myself, so I can't vouch for it, but it claims to do what you're asking for.

The approach that I would probably take is a little more creative (and cheap). One of the features of GA is "*Site Speed*" reports (`Behavior` > `Site Speed` > `Page Timings`). From there, you can select the `Map Overlay` view and see page load speeds by country. Then, you can look at the average page load time for USA visitors and compare that against [countries that generally have slower internet speeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Internet_connection_speeds), like India, the Phillipines, or even Mexico. Of course, you'd need to have a large sample size (ideally tens or hundreds of thousands) for this to be statistically relevant. Even then, it's just an estimation, but it would be one based in real-world numbers that reflect actual usage.

Comment: Regarding your 3rd option, you're comparing the visitor country, not the speed of his internet.

Comment: As the answer says, it's not really possible to reliably and accurately measure the bandwidth of one specific visitor. The solutions proposed here are creative workarounds.